# If/else not being processed correctly? (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

Here's the code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Invoke {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int ret;

        if (args.length<2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: Invoke <class> <method>");
            return;
        }

        if (args.length == 2) {
                ret = 2
        } else {
            System.out.println("Additional parameters not yet supported.");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Results: " + ret);
    }
}
```

The problem is, even if I run the program with something like...

`java -cp Invoke;HelloJava4 Invoke HelloJava4 param1 param2 param3`

... it still recognizes "param1 param2 param3" as one argument.  Note: my system's classpath is set to `C:\JavaSource`, so `-cp Invoke;HelloJava4` makes it search the Invoke and HelloJava4 directories for Invoke.class and HelloJava4.class

If I do `System.out.println(args.length);`, it will output the correct number of arguments given, but when I check it with the following `if` statement, it runs the `if` code block, not the `else` code block.

```
if (args.length == 2) {
    ret = 2
} else {
    System.out.println("Additional parameters not supported yet.");
    return;
}
```

What gives?  :confused:

Here is the unedited code, in full:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Invoke {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object ret;

        for (String arg : args)
            System.out.println(arg);

        System.out.println("Count: " + args.length + " \n");

        if (args.length<2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: Invoke <class> <method>");
            return;
        }

        try {
            Class theClass = Class.forName(args[0]);

            Method theMethod = theClass.getMethod(args[1]);
            if (args.length == 2) {
                System.out.println("Invoking method " + args[1] + " within class " + args[0]);
                ret = theMethod.invoke(null);
            } else {
                // pass parameters to .invoke() if more than two args are given
                // for now, just exit...

                System.out.println("Parameter passing not yet supported.");
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Invoked static method: " + args[1] 
            + " of class: " + args[0]
            + " with no args\nResults: " + ret);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class (" + args[0] + ") not found.");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e2) {
            System.out.println("Class (" + args[0] + ") found, but method does not exist.");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e3) {       
            System.out.println("Class (" + args[0] + ") and method found, but method is not accessible.");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e4) {
            System.out.println("Method threw exception: " + e4.getTargetException() );
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the exact output it gives:

```
C:\JavaSource>cd invoke

C:\JavaSource>javac invoke.java
Note: invoke.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

C:\JavaSource>cd ..

C:\JavaSource>java -cp Invoke;HelloJava4 Invoke HelloJava4 param1 param2 p
aram3
HelloJava4
param1
param2
param3
Count: 4

Class (HelloJava4) found, but method does not exist.
```

Comment: Seriously. Java is in error? I think you'll find that Java processes things just fine including if blocks. When you think it isn't doing so, look extra carefully for the bug in *your* code or in *your* understanding of Java how Java works.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe you; I can't dupe this. You sure you recompiled/etc?

Comment: Have you tried printing the contents of args?

Comment: Works for me, at least when run from [tag:intellij-idea]...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with If/else processing in Java. Whats -cp Invoke;HelloJava4 Invoke HelloJava4 in your command above? Try checking what the content of arguments is?

Comment: So what is your confustion? it was not supposed to execute if block? or it does not execute the else block ?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yep, recompiled several times and also made changes to make sure that I was both compiling and executing the correct file.

Comment: @Michael See esej's answer-like response--a classpath should be directories, jars, or wildcard jars, not classes. Try after fixing your classpath/command-line. It's essentially impossible that if you're running it correctly that it wouldn't work.

Comment: @DaveNewton Invoke and HelloJava4 are a subdirectories (not classes) within the classpath.  The classes are contained within those subdirectories.

Comment: I don't think you are executing the class-file you think you are excuting. Try deleting all class-files "everywhere" and recompile. (It is a guess - but I googled my way to some knowledge that that might be correct syntax for some windows shells.) This is especially likely if you are recompiling and the class-files end up in current-working-directory)

Comment: @Michael Ew; follow Java naming conventions--you already have a class named `Invoke`, having a package named the same thing is pathological. If they're subdirectories within the classpath that's still wrong--you don't need to specify hierarchical classpaths, just the root. If your classes are correctly packaged (which you don't show), it'll work just fine.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am obviously pretty new to Java, seeing as how I am trying to run a class called "HelloJava4".  I am running it in this manner because I wanted each little tutorial project in its own subdirectory instead of having hundreds in the classpath directory.  It's the only way I could get it to work (trying to compile it without the -cp option produces "Error: Could not find or load main class Invoke"), and it does indeed compile and execute.  I don't see how it is possible that using the same name for the directory and the class would produce this problem, but if you can provide a...

Comment: link that shows how to package everything, I could try it.

Comment: @MarkElliot I appended all of the code and edited the original post to reflect the changes.  I also added the output of the new code.  It reads all of the arguments, and it even displays the correct item count when I do `System.out.println("Count: " + args.length + " \n");`, and yet it still does not process the if/else statement correctly

Comment: @Michael See kjp's answer--the program fails before it hits the `if` statement. Java packaging/classpath/etc. is covered in exhaustive detail all over the place, for example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). I recommend *against* using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: "C:\JavaSource>javac invoke.java" and then "C:\JavaSource>java -cp Invoke;HelloJava4 Invoke HelloJava4 param1 ..." probably doesn't invoke the class you want to invoke, since the class compiled by "javac Invoke.java" ends up in current working directory"

Comment: And finally we could maybe conclude that starting with reflection might not be the best approach to learning Java (unless one has "that" level of understanding of language design)

Comment: @esej Hah... tell that to OReilly.  This book could use some more example programs.  It shows 1-5 -line code blocks often, but outside of "Hello, World!", this is the first example program, and it's on page 205.  (Learning Java, Third Edition... a book for beginners, allegedly!)

Comment: Haha! Reflection is complicated. I would jump to the Collection chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your unedited code, the exception is thrown from this line.

```
Method theMethod = theClass.getMethod(args[1]);
```

It doesn't even reach the if/else condition for number of arguments.

Comment: Doh.  That should have been obvious.  Bad choice of parameters on my part, as param1 does not exist as a method within HelloJava4.  :(  However, it doesn't even work if I execute it with `java -cp Invoke;HelloJava4 Invoke HelloJava4 main`, so you're right about it being a problem with this line, but I am still stumped on why it won't work even when I specify a method that does indeed exist.

Comment: I tried this and I cannot reproduce this. I am able to get it working properly.
      C:\Users\kjp>type Invoke.java
      C:\Users\kjp>java Invoke String 1 2 3
Additional parameters not yet supported.

C:\Users\kjp>java Invoke String 1 2
Additional parameters not yet supported.

C:\Users\kjp>java Invoke String 1
Results: 2

Comment: Bah.  Just figured it out.  The book's example of `java Invoke java.lang.System currentTimeMillis` works as well.  The problem is that HelloJava4's main method also has parameters (though I couldn't tell you why, as it doesn't use them), and I'm searching for `public static void main()` instead of `public static void main(String[] args)`.  Sigh.  I'm a dummy.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  ^_^

Comment: This is why it is always good to add e.printStackTrace() statements in your Exception handlers. It will tell you the exact line where the exception is thrown, will help in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

> java -cp Invoke;HelloJava4 Invoke HelloJava4 param1 param2 param3

That is not right. I don't know what OS nor what shell you use to execute that line.

I don't think the:

> -cp Invoke;HelloJava4

is correct. (The reason I'm saying that is because you are experiencing none-reproducable problems.)

To verify, execute the snippet you gave us without any -cp or -classpath.

edit:
If we assume the -cp argument is correct.
Meaning that the jvm is started with the directories Invoke and HelloJava4 in the classpath (-cp/-classpath overrides the environmental variable specifying a classpath) the jvm will look in the directories Invoke and HelloJava4 for the Invoke class. This means that you are probably executing another class than you think you are.

You example code is in the default package.
Just go to the directory where the sourcefile is and execute:

```
javac Invoke.java
java -cp . Invoke param1 param2 param3 [...]
```

(the point says the current directory is in the classpath ...)

And you should see a different result.